# Implementing a free trial period with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, trialware

I am trying to implement a recurring subscription service on a website using PayPal however I would like to offer a free trial period before the user is billed and the subscription is started. Is this possible using PayPal's API?

I have very little experience using the PayPal API and cannot seem to find any useful documentation about implementing a free trial period, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question.  But why not lock the trial period to the users account and if they choose to continue when it exires then send them to PayPal to pay for their recurring subscription?

I suspect that if you expect them to enter credit card information just to get a trial you will have a very low rate of free trials.

Comment: @cbailey

This is actually how I had planned to implement the feature however the client I am doing the work for has made clear that users must be automatically billed after the trial period has ended if they don't cancel their account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

[Recurring Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments) - Documentation on PayPal website

> **Trial period:**
>   An optional subscription period before theregular payment period begins. A trial period may not have the samebilling cycles and payment amounts as the regular payment period.

Comment: Re: my comment above.  I'm guessing you want to lock to PayPal accounts for your trial as they are more scarce then a standard "email validated" account on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this class from

php classes
  [1]: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4932-PHP-Create-buttons-and-process-Paypal-payments.html To download this you may need to register.