# How is PayPal accepting payment for the first month free? After first month it will pay.

Tags: paypal

I have create a plan for directory Access on my site. my site is based in real estate directory access plan is $8.99/month i want to create a functionality for first month free access then after every month pay charge $8.99. I have also added recurring function for PayPal.

Please help me how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/#include-an-optional-trial-period

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-freeTrialRecurringPayments-curl-etc/

[Implementing a free trial period with PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470353/implementing-a-free-trial-period-with-paypal)

You can use the trial option.